# Looking for in-memory scalable object repository with up to 150 million small objects in .net

Tags: .net, in-memory-database, scalable

I am currently working on a data management system that needs to calculate huge amounts of data: think of an excel sheet with about 150 million cells with data.

We use a sql server database to store the data but the calculation performance is sub-optimal due to many reasons. While considering alternatives, I thought giving a try to in-memory object structures.

Here are the basic requirements:

1. We need a structure that supports multiple users making updates on the same "sheet" of my excel analogy. If performance of a single update is high enough, serializing updates of all users are acceptable
2. We absolutely cannot accept data loss
3. We need indexes on the object key, but also some indexes on partial keys, so the in-memory structure must support non-unique keys, resulting in efficient searches on partial keys returning a collection of matching records
4. Must support .NET

Given these conditions, any suggestions please?

Thank you,

Kemal

Comment: How large are this cells? Is it really feasible to keep them in memory? SQL server usually does a pretty good job when given enough memory and proper indexes. And the no data loss requirement is another good reason *not* to keep it in memory.

Comment: Each of these cells contain (on average, depending on key size) 50 bytes. So, yes, I believe it is feasible to keep all data in memory. I am exploring this as an alternative to try out for the next version of the application in addition to current sql server based model, which can also be improved a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about a NoSQL database  over a relational database? Something like MongoDB or RavenDB?

[Mongo](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=mongodb&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDMQFjAA&url=http://www.mongodb.org/&ei=bL_0ToLrGIKWswbdnoCEBg&usg=AFQjCNFkupTrrD2YYX6ydM2wb9IbWll3Vw) is an in-memory database and I believe [Raven](http://ravendb.net/faq/embedded-with-http) can be configured to run in-memory.

There's various flavours of NoSQL databases too.  Some are geared for 'read-heavy' apps and some for 'write-heavy' apps.

You might also want to look at [CQRS](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html) if you'd benefit from pre-calculating common searches or calculations.

I would expect the 'no data loss' requirement to be your biggest deciding factor though.

Comment: would you suggest me one that you have some personal experience with please?

Comment: I'll look into both mongo and CouchDB. Thanks for the answer

Comment: I've had experience with Mongo.  It's great, but bear in mind it has severe size restrictions in 32 bit: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/FAQ#FAQ-Whatarethe32bitlimitations%3F

Answer (score 0):

[Raima Inc](http://www.raima.com/products/rdme/) is another No-SQL database that runs in-memory, on-disk or a hybrid of the two.

Regarding data loss, there are extensions available to provide mirroring and replication.

Here is a link of the complete technical specs of their database: [RDM Embedded 10.1 Architecture and Features](http://raima.com/wp-content/uploads/RDMe-10-1-Technical-Summary.pdf)

Comment: If you are associated with this company, it is polite to say so.